# Is there any implimentation of FP growth in R

Tags: r

I have the following item sets, and i need to find the most frequeent items using FP Tree.

```
C D E
A D
B C E
B C D E
A C D
```

I have been looking for a sample of code which shows how FP works in R.
I have been searching in web for a while and the only thing i got is, this [link](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Data_Mining_Algorithms_In_R/Frequent_Pattern_Mining/The_FP-Growth_Algorithm#Implementation_in_R)

which doesn't have a proper code. 
I have also checked the documentation of `arules` package, but i didn't find anything related to `FP Tree`

Answer (score 1):

Download the FP-growth-Frequent c code from http://www.borgelt.net//fpgrowth.html, then embed it in R.

```
cd /home/incas/download/fpgrowth/fpgrowth/src/
make
./fpgrowth -m2 -n5 -s0.075 /home/incas/experiment/test.dat frequent
```

Comment: what does `make` do?

Comment: what does `-m2 -n5 -s0.075` do?